# How can I use gradle uploadArchive with other ssh port?

Tags: maven, deployment, ssh, gradle, port

I'm using gradle to upload my package to my ssh server.

it like gradle offical guide:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories  {
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            repository(url: "scp://repos.xxx.com/release") {
                authentication(userName: "maven", password: "maven")
            }
            pom.groupId = 'com.xxx'
        }

    }
}
```

But my ssh'port is not 22, and I can't find the port configuration.

I change the url to 'scp://repos:2233/release', it not work.

I check the wagon-ssh source and not found the port config, so I think the only config position is the url.

But I dont know how to config it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I know where the problem is, when I execute the `uploadArchives` command, the SSH  will be asked to save authentication information for the first time, but this is covered with gradle output.

I see it When I add `--info` to the cmd, and input the `yes`, the process can continue.

Change port is simple: `scp://repos.xxx.com:1234/release`